# Remove Particular style from jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

The links that are part of text in the jQuery UI Dialog gets a black color from ui css using the class `ui-widget-content`. I can override and apply new color to the content. But i want that css from not applying to the links. Removing that class is not applicable.

```
.ui-widget-content a{
    color : #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: You want to keep `.ui-widget-content color` _except_ for anchor tags?

Comment: Yes. I only want to keep `ui-widget-content` class

Answer (score 0):

This may help you with the issue. See the CSS I coded below

```css
.ui-widget-content > a:link, .ui-widget-content > a:visited{
    color : #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="ui-widget-content">
<p>paragraph</p>
<a href="#"> this is a link because it has an href attr</a>
</div>
```